# Do I need to file I-765 for the adjustment from H1b to Marriage Green Card

Tags: usa, h1-visa, greencard

I'm currently on H1B and it will expire in two years. I recently got married to a US Citizen and would like to file I-130 and I-485 concurrently. My question is do I need to file I-765 at all? If I need to file I-765, why? I still have plenty of time on my H1B. I'm not sure what the EAD from I-765 would give me more than my current H1B. Is it the benefit that I could switch job without H1B transfer with that EAD?

Please help me understand this role of I-765 in my case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both I-765 for EAD and I-131 for Advance Parole are free for I-485 applicants. So there is no downside to applying for them. You should apply for them even if you don't plan on using them, for just in case the situation changes. An EAD will allow you to work for any job in case you change jobs.